# how to take HTML form input, run input through python program, output response in HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, html

I have a massive python script that gives a specific output. the only input required is a zip code. I can use an HTML form to get the zipcode, how do i then take the variable input by the user and run that through my python script on the back end and then print the results from the python script in the html?

basically, I'm using bootstrap studio to make a base website for what i'm doing and the studio allows me to include my own code snippets and write my own html, so the plan is to just include this on my page in bootstrap studio when i figure out how to do it, and from there I can launch my site. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Like I said, my python script is massive so I'll just use a tiny program for now because theoretically it would be the same concept. Below is my code, the issue is instead of running the python script with the userinput, it just prints the whole python script on another page

This would be the html I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action = "file:///C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Python-1.py" method = "post">
First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name"><br />
Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name" />

<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

This would be the python

```
# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Another issue is that I want to be able to print the output on the page the form was on or at least a copy of that page, and I don't want to have to rewrite an entire webpage in python if that makes sense. Sorry for the extensive and probably sloppy explanation, I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: do you want to add Python code in Boostrap Studio? Are you sure it can run Python? I doubt.

Comment: inside one script you can `import` another script and it will run it. Or you can use module `subprocess` to run another script as external program and grab text printed by this program.

Comment: I would use Flask instead of `cgi` or at least template system `Jinja2` - it can get HTML file and replace `{{ variable }}` with value. This way you could put text on form page. If you don't want Jinja then you can put `%s` in HTML file and read this file in Python and put text in place of `%s` - like you put (first_name, last_name)

Comment: instead of this `print` you could read all text from file to variable `html` and then do `print html % (first_name, last_name)`

Comment: So if i'm using flask, how do I pass the variable that I've gotten from the html form into my python file and then put an output back in? All I can find with flask is how to pull info directly from the page, modify it in the def() portion under the route decorator and send it back. I want to modify the data in a completely separate file and i don't know how to store the variable in the file, use the user in that file and then call back the result